# how to use ICU java API for encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, icu

I have a byte[] array and I have to convert it to **"Unicode, UnicodeWithBOM e.t.c"**

I tried **ICU** library but unable to find any solution.

is there any functions available in **`ICU`** for java to  **ConvertToUnicode,ConvertToUnicodeWithBOM,ConvertFromUnicode** e.t.c

[Please refer the ICU library for the java](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/)

I have gone through the library  but unable to find the exact class and the methods which will convert a particular source string into another format.

e.g : I have array of byte in UTF-8 format and I wanted the same to be converted into the byte array of ANSCI/UTF-16/

Comment: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: hello @jww ,i have byte array and i want to convert it into any encoding type

Comment: @jww : Please check the updated question and let me know if it gives any more clarification